# How can I make everything below an object (arrangement wise) transparent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

For instance, I have a line with a stroke colored navy blue over a shape. How can I make the area covered by the navy blue line transparent, including that area on the shape below?

Comment: @OrionGL This question decisively requires a screenshot and some explanation about the efforts done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if I understood your question right (using Illustrator CS 6):

1. We start with this shape:

[image]

2. Select the dotted line and from the main menu select *Object/Expand Appearance*
3. Select the dotted line again and select *Object/Expand*

Step 2 and 3 will make each dot of the line to become separate objects.

[image]

4. Select both the dotted line and the background and from the Pathfinder panel, chose *Minus Front*

[image]

5. This will be the result

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter if the line is dotted, has a stroke etc. It is what you select from the line that will be subtracted from the background in step 4.